# Issue with multilabel classification

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24
and wrote some of my code for multilabel classification. I had it working with one-hot encoding on a small scale but I had to move to option 2 mentioned in the article because I have 6000 classes and therefore one hot was not viable. I managed to train the network and it said 99% accuracy and 83% f1 score. However, when I'm trying to test the network, for every image it's outputting some combination of only 3 labels when there are 6000 possible labels. I wondered if maybe the code to test the model was incorrect. I tried using the code mentioned in the post and it doesn't work:

```
test_generator.reset()
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST, verbose=1);
pred_bool = (pred > 0.5)
```

> unorderable `types: list() > float()`

I've tried hard to fix this and not figured it out and I can't find any examples online of anyone doing something similar. Does anyone have an idea of how to get this prediction part working using this code block (I had it with another 2 options and was getting that issue printing one or several labels) or why the model might be failing in training with this behavior?

EDIT: for more context on the training issue, here is all the training code:

```
import json
input_file = open ('class_names_6000.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
#print(str(json_array))

args = parser.parse_args()
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
print('Loading Data...')
df = pd.read_csv('dataset_train.csv')
df["labels"]=df["labels"].apply(lambda x:x.split(","))
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="",
x_col="Filepaths",
y_col="labels",
batch_size=128,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
classes=json_array,
target_size=(100,100))

df = pd.read_csv('dataset_test.csv')
df["labels"]=df["labels"].apply(lambda x:x.split(","))
test_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="",
x_col="Filepaths",
y_col="labels",
batch_size=128,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
classes=json_array,
target_size=(100,100))

df = pd.read_csv('dataset_validation.csv')
df["labels"]=df["labels"].apply(lambda x:x.split(","))
valid_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="",
x_col="Filepaths",
y_col="labels",
batch_size=128,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
classes=json_array,
target_size=(100,100))
print('Data Loaded.')

f1_score_callback = ComputeF1()
model = build_model('train', numclasses=len(json_array), model_name = args.model)

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

**Also, an important detail, when training, it says the accuracy is 99% and the f1 score is 84% with an validation f1 score at 84% as well.**

Comment: 1) please **proofread** *after* posting (your code was incorrectly formatted - fixed it for you this time) 2) since the error happens at `pred_bool = (pred > 0.5)`, all code that comes *after* this line is irrelevant (never executed), it just creates unnecessary clutter, and should not be included here; the same holds for code *before* the error that is irrelevant to it (removed).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of your `pred`

Comment: predict_generator() returns a list of probabilities

Comment: For a detailed traceback follow the link below:

https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720

Comment: Well I included the code after it because I was able to get prediction to work using other methods but the output seemed incorrect. So, I was also wondering if anyone had an idea as to why the training might be only outputting a couple classes. After looking at the predicta bit more, I doubt it is an issue just with the predict and likely is a training issue.

Comment: Just tried with 20 classes and it works fine. So now that it seems like the issue is related to the number of classes, does anyone have any ideas what might be causing the issue?